# Can't compile mongodb 2.0 c++ driver

Tags: c++, mongodb, compiler-errors, driver

I tried to build mongodb c++ 2.0 driver,but got the following error message:

> security_commands.cpp:(.text+0x865): undefined reference to
>   `mongo::CmdAuthenticate::getUserObj(std::basic_string<char,
>   std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&,
>   std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >
>   const&, mongo::BSONObj&, std::basic_string<char,
>   std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
>   security_commands.cpp:(.text+0xa59): undefined reference to`
>   mongo::CmdAuthenticate::authenticate(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&,
>   std::basic_string, std::allocator >
>   const&, bool)' mongo/db/security_commands.os: In function
>   `_GLOBAL__sub_I_security_commands.cpp':
>   security_commands.cpp:(.text.startup+0x1a6): undefined reference to`
>   vtable for mongo::CmdLogout' mongo/db/security_common.os: In function
>   `mongo::AuthenticationInfo::_isAuthorized(std::basic_string, std::allocator > const&, int) const':

Comment: You're not linking to the correct libraries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tarball for the driver seems to be missing mongo/db/security.cpp file among others to make a shared lib.

But, it has enough for building static lib with few missing symbol.

open SConstruct and comment out the line saying

> libs += env.SharedLibrary( "mongoclient" , allClientFiles )

and you are set.